# grep to find a string, get the line before and after with no line numbers displayed

Tags: grep

Recently I had a need to search for a particular string in a file and I needed to display the line before and the line after the match.

File

```
AAAA
BBBB                      
CCCC
DDDD
```

Using google I found the following solution utilizing grep.

```
grep -n1 BBBB File
```

Which outputs,

```
1-AAAA
2-BBBB
3-CCCC
```

So this does what I want except it displays the line numbers in the output.

Is there a way to suppress the line numbers?

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
grep -C 1 BBBB input
```

`grep` has three options for showing context lines:

> ```
>   -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
>           Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line  containing  --  between  contiguous  groups  of
>           matches.
>   -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
>           Print  NUM  lines  of  leading  context  before matching lines.  Places a line containing -- between contiguous groups of
>           matches.
>   -C NUM, --context=NUM
>           Print NUM lines of output context.  Places a line containing -- between contiguous groups of matches.
> ```

Comment: Way cool! That way  I can get X number of lines before, after or both! That will come in handy, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `n`

```sh
grep -1 BBBB input
```

also with `sed`

```sh
sed -n 'N;N;/\n.*BBBB.*\n/p' input
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks, as you probably figured out I'm new to this :-)